# Laptop freezes every time I click on taskbar

Tags: windows-explorer, freeze, crash

I deleted some of my %temp% files earlier today in my other laptop, and after logging in again the taskbar is frozen. Every time I try clicking on the taskbar a black screen flashes and screen remains frozen. I tried all possible methods of restarting the explorer.exe, scanned for corrupt files using sfc command and also tried resetting the video driver but nothing seems to help. Please aid me, thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a result of corrupted system files _(`Dism`, `Sfc`, or a Repair Install won't resolve it)_, it's a result of corruption within the User Profile, such as what @John suggested [shell context, etc.] _(deleting files from `%Temp%` wouldn't result in this - correlation doesn't equal causation)_ - either [find](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/folder-redirection/troubleshoot-user-profiles-events)/fix the corruption or create a [new](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-a-corrupted-user-profile-in-windows-1cf41c18-7ce3-12f9-8e1d-95896661c5c9) User Profile

Comment: I did make a new profile yet the same problem exists.

Comment: Just to verify, you created a new user, logged into that user, and the problem still existed prior to copying any data over to the new user profile? Generally, shell contexts and similar are `HKCU` specific, not `HKLM`, albeit it could be something within `HKCR` [Registry Hives]. You'll likely want to use Nirsoft [Shell*View] or SysInternals utilities to narrow down what contexts are the issue by disabling half, seeing if the problem still exists, re-enabling, then disabling the other half, and if the issue goes away, continue to winnow down by disabling half of that group, etc.

Comment: stop svhosts.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried all possible methods of restarting the explorer.exe, scanned
> for corrupt files using sfc command and also tried resetting the video
> driver but nothing seems to help.

This is most likely a shell context or equally troublesome error.

You can try a new Windows Account.

Most likely however, you need to do a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.
If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

Try Option 1 (Keep Everything) first.

(1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup, but generally nothing will be lost.

(2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive. Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always have a backup, but data is not usually lost.

(3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged, because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It depends on the precise situation.

Comment: If the issue is some kind of corruption within the User Profile, a Repair Install will not resolve it _(a Repair Install doesn't modify user profiles, it only replaces system files, specifically those files contained within an `install.esd`||`install.wim`)_ - either the corruption would have to be found and fixed or a new user profile created, all data moved to it, and the old user profile deleted.

Comment: Grateful for your answer, @John but this does not seem to help, Thanks again!

Comment: If the first option does not help, back up all your stuff and use Option 3:  Keep  Nothing.  That is very close to a fresh install and this should now work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but the problem is somehow related to graphic related issues.
to get rid of this, you should disable transparency ii color in personalization and you will be just fine. It is working just fine for me.
I did not test this one, but you can upgrade Graphic Driver to see if it is gone or not.
regards.